# SQL Obtain total amount of deleted lines in file with multiple DELETE queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I put an example

In a SQL script with a hundred or more delete queries the output should be like that:
Note: The deletes cannot be made using a unique delete query.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    1 row deleted.
    Commit complete.

Is it possible to obtain a count of total lines deleted like.

```
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.
1 row deleted.

16 row deleted.
Commit complete.
```

I could also be valid for update or insert commands.

Comment: The output you are talking about does not come from the database. It comes from some "client" program that connects to the database and displays a result on your screen. People often forget this basic and very important fact. Are you using SQLPlus? If so, then the answer is simple: SQLPlus has a list of commands, and there is no command to get what you want. On the other hand, SQLPlus and other client programs can display the contents of the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer. The answer by Littlefoot shows how to use PL/SQL to write to that buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQL%ROWCOUNT` is what comes in mind. However & unfortunately, I can't make it work at SQL level. Here's an example: it is a .SQL script which sets a variable, deletes some rows from two tables and *tries to* calculate total number of deleted rows.

```
var total number;

delete from a where deptno = 10;
exec :total := nvl(:total, 0) + sql%rowcount;

delete from b where deptno = 10;
exec :total := nvl(:total, 0) + sql%rowcount;

print total
```

When I ran it, I got:

```
SQL> @p

3 rows deleted.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


1 row deleted.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


     TOTAL
----------
```

Total is `NULL` because `SQL%ROWCOUNT` is `NULL` (I know; I tried with `NVL(SQL%ROWCOUNT, -1)` and got `-2` as a result.

---

But, if you switch to PL/SQL - which might be possible, by enclosing your `DELETE` statements into `BEGIN-END` - then there's some improvement. A new .SQL script:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_total number := 0;
begin
  delete from a where deptno = 10;
  l_total := l_total + sql%rowcount;

  delete from b where deptno = 10;
  l_total := l_total + sql%rowcount;

  dbms_output.put_line('Deleted total of ' || l_total || ' rows');
end;
/
```

Testing:

```
SQL> @p
Deleted total of 4 rows

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If that satisfies your needs, good. If not, I'm afraid I wouldn't know how to do what you want.

Comment: Seems good. Now i can't test the solution but many thanks for your answer.